# L' «engagement vers la mise en œuvre » ?

Tags: prépositions, formulation-idiomatique, droit-et-justice

Dans un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/politique-canadienne/201902/05/01-5213683-langues-autochtones-ottawa-depose-un-projet-de-loi-historique.php), je lis ce qui suit :

> Le gouvernement de Justin Trudeau ne cache pas d'ailleurs que le
>   [projet de loi](http://www.parl.ca/LegisInfo/BillDetails.aspx?Language=F&billId=10293463) s'inscrit dans le sillage des conclusions de la
>   [Commission de vérité et réconciliation du Canada](https://www.rcaanc-cirnac.gc.ca/fra/1450124405592/1529106060525), qui a entre
>   autres qualifié l'époque noire des pensionnats autochtones de «
>   [génocide culturel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnocide#%C2%AB_Ethnocide_%C2%BB_et_%C2%AB_g%C3%A9nocide_culturel_%C2%BB) », et de son **engagement vers la mise en œuvre** de
>   la [Déclaration des Nations unies sur les droits des peuples
>   autochtones](https://www.un.org/development/desa/indigenous-peoples-fr/drip.html).
>
> [ *Langues autochtones: Ottawa dépose un projet de loi historique*, La
>   Presse, 5 février 2019. ]

Je ne sais pas s'il s'agit d'une traduction (ou d'un anglicisme relié à l'idée de [*commitment*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/lex/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lang_indx=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_c_fra&xxx=CERTITUDE&page=9tUXEFoGgVpY.html#zz9tUXEFoGgVpY) ?) ou simplement d'un emploi particulier de l'[*engagement*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/clefsfp-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=commitment&i=&cur=1&nmbr=&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) influencée par l'idée de [*cheminer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cheminer) (vers). Quoiqu'il en soit je trouve personnellement la formulation inusitée et la [cascade de noms](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=9bqvu6yZhhYQ.html), bizarre.

---

Peut-on expliquer si la formulation est adéquate ; autrement suffit-il de remplacer la préposition [*vers*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vers/2) et si oui, par quoi ; autrement a-t-on une intuition de ce qui constituerait une meilleure tournure, s'appuie-t-elle sur l'emploi d'un ou de deux verbes, doit-on reculer dans la phrase pour y effectuer un autre changement ?

Answer (score 2):

Dans ce passage, le mot « engagement » à une signification proche des mots « implication », et « volonté ».

Le mot « vers » sert à indiquer que l’objectif de cet engagement est « la mise en œuvre de la Déclaration…» (Édit : il peut aussi être remplacé par le mot « pour »)

Answer (score 0):

La formulation de "engagement **vers** la mise en œuvre" me semble tout à fait adéquate. En vu de la définition* de cette dernière, nous pourrions interpréter ces mots de la manière suivante:

> Promesse de mettre en œuvre

De plus 37% de la population d'Ottawa est parfaitement bilingue, ajouté au fait que le Français et l'anglais sont les deux langues officielles je ne pense pas que le problème soit lié à un anglicisme quelconque.

> *Définition de **mise en œuvre:** Action de mettre en œuvre quelque chose ; résultat de cette action. Source [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mise_en_%C5%93uvre)

Comment: Comme vous pouvez le constater [ici](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/livrer+un+discours.html) avec ces domaines gc.ca,  le fait qu'on soit bilingue à Ottawa n'est un gage d'absolument rien en ce qui a trait à la qualité du français ou à l'emploi d'[anglicismes](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_l&page=9Qj0yJPZhQAA.html)... Une université francophone en Ontario ne nuirait certainement pas...

Answer (score 0):

En éliminant de la phrase la première des expressions coordonnées on obtient ceci :

> « Le gouvernement de Justin Trudeau ne cache pas d'ailleurs que le projet de loi s'inscrit dans le sillage de son engagement vers la mise en œuvre de la Déclaration des Nations unies sur les droits des peuples autochtones. ».

Si on parle du sillage d'un engagement on parle de choses qui ont un rapport avec cet engagement, plus, on parle de chose qui lui sont subséquentes et non parties constituantes, ce qui signifie généralement des choses accessoires, moins importantes, des choses qui découlent d'un élément principal. Comme il est question dans la déclaration de multiples doits relatifs au langages autochtones,

> - «  revivifier, d’utiliser, de développer et de transmettre aux générations futures leur langue,  leur système d’écriture et leur littérature…»,
> - « Les peuples autochtones ont le droit d’établir et de contrôler leurs propres systèmes et établissements scolaires où l’enseignement est dispensé dans leur propre langue… »
> - « Les peuples autochtones ont le droit d’établir leurs propres médias dans leur propre langue… »
> - « …les autochtones […] puissent accéder, lorsque cela est possible, à un enseignement dispensé […] dans leur propre langue… »,

il est clair que les questions en matière de langages autochtones sont des éléments principaux de la charte incarnées dans des directives spécifiques et non laissées en tant que dépendantes de directives générales sur la culture. Les réponses de la charte à ces questions en sont donc des parties constituantes. Il s'ensuit que leur prise en compte dans le projet de loi constitue une partie de la mise en œuvre ; selon ce je crois que l'on puisse entendre par sillage, quelque peu mis au clair ci-dessus, ce terme ne convient pas, et il aurait été correct de parler de « cadre de l'engagement ». Avec cette modification, la cascade de noms, certes un peu longue et donc difficile à lire, ne présente selon moi aucun écueil logique.